# hyundai creta low mileage in city

Tags: car, hyundai

My Hyundai creta petrol AT is one and a half month old. I have run it 3200 kms by now. First servicing of the car done at 1500 Kms. In four lane road with cruise control on at 80 kms per hour it gave close 16 Kms per litre. In double road with speeds not exceeding 80 Kms per hour with  cruise control off it gave 12.5 kms per litre. In city driving it gives 6 to 6.5 kms per litre. I don't know the reason why it gives low mileage in city (Hyderabad) driving. Will the mileage in city driving will ever increase.

Comment: No, that is the obvious difference between cruising and town driving.

Comment: Watch the RPM's as you take off from stopped and as the car moves through the gears. Higher RPM's = more fuel use. Now watch the RPM's @ 80 in cruise control. Should see a clear pattern. It is unlikely that your new car has any issues such as small vacuum leak triggering increased fuel injection during lower RPM's, so suspect that is just how your car is and will be. No breaking in is going to change it.